# bitwise & doesn't work with bytes in kotlin

Tags: bit-manipulation, kotlin

I'm trying to write kotlin code like:

```
for (byte b : hash)  
     stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b&0xff));
```

but I have nothing to do with the "&". I'm trying to use "b and 0xff" but it doesn't work. The bitwise "and" seems to work on Int, not byte.

```
java.lang.String.format("%02x", (b and 0xff))
```

it's ok to use

```
1 and 0xff
```

Comment: Could you please explain what your code does? I've never seen such syntax before

Comment: Instead of `java.lang.String.format`: [`byte.toString(2)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-string.html).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Kolin provides bitwise operator-like [infix functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#operations) available for `Int` and `Long` only.

So it's necessary to convert bytes to ints to perform bitwise ops:

```
val b : Byte = 127
val res = (b.toInt() and 0x0f).toByte() // evaluates to 15
```

**UPDATE:**
Since Kotlin 1.1 these operations are available directly on Byte.

From *bitwiseOperations.kt*:

```
@SinceKotlin("1.1") 
public inline infix fun Byte.and(other: Byte): Byte = (this.toInt() and other.toInt()).toByte()
```

Comment: It's also useful to note that java does this widening conversion too. It's just implicit.

Answer (score 7):

Bitwise "and" of any byte-value and 0xff will always return the original value.

It is simple to see this if you draw the bits in a diagram:

```
00101010   42
11111111   and 0xff
--------
00101010   gives 42
```

Comment: No, it's used to truncate an `int` so it fits in a byte.

Comment: @AllenVork bytes in java are *signed* and java converts them implicitly to an `int` when doing bitwise operations (Kotlin simply requires this to be explicit). Therefore, in order for this widening conversion to result in the expected positive int value when the initial byte value is negative, one masks the 3 higher-order bytes of the widened int value (which includes the sign bit) via the `& 0xff`.

Comment: Oh, `x & 0xff` is such a cool way to convert to int.  Thanks, I'm gonna use it everywhere now.  It's gonna make me look so clever!