# Unsigned lexical comparison of ByteArray

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have two byte arrays and I would like to compare them. I have a loop like this (for clarity, its more of a *Javaish* loop):

```
for (i in 0..63) {
    if (newArray[i] != oldArray[i]) {
        return newArray[i] < oldArray[i]
    }
}
```

For example, `newArray[0]` is `0x93` and `oldArray[0]` is `0x00`. This still returns *true* (meaning newArray is smaller than oldArray) because it is done as a signed comparison. Is there a way to compare absolute (unsigned) values? Or a collection to compare byte arrays?

Comment: Normally these kind of lexicographical comparisons (where the "alphabet" is a byte value in the range 0x00 to 0xFF) return -1, 0 or 1 for smaller than, equal to or larger than.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert signed `Byte` to unsigned byte value by converting it to a larger data type (like `Int`, `Long`) and then [bitwise and] it and `0xFF`.

```
for (i in 0..63) {
    if (newArray[i] != oldArray[i]) {
        return (newArray[i].toInt() and 0xFF) < (oldArray[i].toInt() and 0xFF)
    }
}
```

You can make an extension function if you use it a lot.

```
fun Byte.toUnsignedValue(): Int = this.toInt() & 0xFF

for (i in 0..63) {
    if (newArray[i] != oldArray[i]) {
        return newArray[i].toUnsignedValue() < oldArray[i].toUnsignedValue()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no bitwise and operation in `Byte` and `Short` in low-version Kotlin (or without experimental feature enabled): [bitwise & doesn't work with bytes in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411476/bitwise-doesnt-work-with-bytes-in-kotlin)

And, JVM have no unsigned data types except `char`, which is 2-byte unsigned.

[Why doesn't Java support unsigned ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints)

It's like there is no operator overloading in Java. Kotlin added operator overloads, but adding unsigned data types is more fundamental problem because JVM inherently does not have them.

---

You can compare two byte arrays without for loop using `zip` method, but it will create a new `List`, so it will be slower than the for-loop method.

Comment: There's [Byte.toUnsignedInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-) since Java 8.

Comment: Yep, and a lot of those functions will get optimized...